# Pass a function as a first argument in a function call in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

In the following code

```
x= (f,n) -> f(n)
...
x( (n) -> n+1 , 5) #parse error
```

How can I fix the parse error above ?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A pair of parenthesis would fix this problem, just found the answer on IRC.

```
x( (n) -> n+1  , 5) #parse error
x ((n) -> n+1) , 5 #fixed
```

Answer (score 19):

I usually do either this:

```
foo ->
  doStuff('foo')
, 5
```

or this:

```
fn = -> doStuff('foo')
foo fn, 5
```

Wrapping extra parens inside argument lists never sat right with me as it's tough for my brain to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Ali's answer is slightly different to the question he asked. One correct solution is

```
x = (f,n) -> f(n)

x(( -> n+1), 5)
```